# MediaPlayer Redirect return http 307 on Android 2.2

Tags: android, media-player, android-2.2-froyo, http-status-code-307

I have an app using the MediaPlayer class... It has always worked on 1.6 and 2.1 devices, but since I have beentesting on a 2.2 device (and the emulator) I have noticed that it won't stream a mp3 file if a redirect takes place first...
It will return the following :

```
12-04 11:40:48.813: ERROR/HTTPDataSource(34): HTTP request failed w/ http status 307
12-04 11:40:48.813: INFO/AwesomePlayer(34): mConnectingDataSource->connect() returned -1004
12-04 11:40:48.813: ERROR/MediaPlayer(2305): error (1, -1004)
12-04 11:40:48.813: ERROR/MediaPlayer(2305): Error (1,-1004)
```

I was wondering if anyone has noticed this behavior and if so if anyone has any solution for the problem ? It might be an "AwesomePlayer" but it doesnt behave any better than it predecessor :(

Answer (score 0):

As much as i have been played with MediaPlayer Class, I think you Have to give final URL ( NO REDIRECTION ) to MediaPlayer. 
i faced similar problem in one of my project.

**Sol:** find out some way to get final redirected-url.